# How to execution ng-repeat after json is loaded

Tags: json, angularjs-ng-repeat

i need some advice to time my angularJs application to work properly.
It should work like following:

1. request some json data ($http)
2. set requested data in $rootScope.data
3. execute ng-repeat after json is available

But what it does is, ng-repeat is trying to run through the json whish is not available.
It spreads `undefined` all over the place.

Help would be kindly appreciated.
OliverKK

Comment: some code please? you probably did something like this `$rootScope.data = $http.get('/something'/);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.ngRepData =[];
```

Then on `$http.get('someURL.json').success`  do:

```
$http.get('someURL.json).success(function(data){
    $scope.ngRepData =data;
}
```

Since the array object used in the `ngRepeat` is initialized as empty `ngRepeat` will not render anything, only until the http request is ready.